# How to send data from Steam OpenId login to mySQL Database?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, steam

I created my steam openId login for my CS:GO League website.

I used this tutorial: https://youtu.be/7IzEqAK_PLg

Now my question is, how can I save the data such as Steam ID, Username, etc. in MySQL?

I’m a beginner so I don’t really know.

Answer (score 0):

So around ~5:30 in, you see code which has $steamID64 which is the openid validated steam id from the openid_claimed_id $_GET param.

From here if you're just using basic PHP to do this, you'll probably want to use PDO MySQL functions:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059

Although it may be simpler to use an ORM class - https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm

As far as getting the username from the steam ID that may be a little beyond the scope of the question, but looks like there's some documentation for it:

https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/1700541698685553363/

https://steamapi.xpaw.me/#ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries